# Gnome Shell Menu Crashes

Tags: gnome

The Gnome menu is crashing when I install the gnome-shell-extensions-alternative-status-menu, installed via Terminal or Synaptic. When I remove it, the menu stays put. Any ideas how to install a Shutdown button to the menu without it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Gnome Shell menu crash is caused by not having a user profile picture set. To set a user profile picture, click on your name in the Gnome Shell menu, then click System Settings.[image]

Then, select User Accounts from the System Settings box. [image]

Now, click the Unlock button at the top right corner of the User Accounts window, and click on the picture next to your name, and select the one you want. Now, you can install gnome-shell-extensions-alternative-status-menu, and it will not cause the menu to disappear.

Comment: Worked!  How do I give you a point.  I'm new to all this...

Comment: To give me reputation, or a point, click on the up arrow next to my answer.